# spring-security-facebook plugin grails - logout

Tags: facebook, grails

I am playing with the grails spring security facebook plugin which is made easy to connect to application using facebook login. I have some questions on logout and redirection on login.

1. When I logout from the example app, it says logged out (redirect to j_spring_security_logout). However, when I click login again, it logs back in without popping up the login page. How is the logout supposed to work?
2. I followed this example and integrated into an existing grails application with spring security, with server side auth. If I do not define grails.serverURL in config.groovy, the redirection doesn't work since the there is a missing "/" before j_sprint_secutity_facebook_check. (http://j_spring_security_facebook_check...).
   If I add the grails.serverURL, it is adding an additional "/" into other page urls and breaking the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you're already granted access, Facebook just redirects back to app (with new access_token).
2. Try version 0.10.3

Comment: Excellent. 0.10.3. Solves the problem, Thanks Igor.

Comment: Excellent. 1) I get it now. 2) 0.10.3. Solves the problem   Thanks so much for the wonderful plugin & support - Igor. As per 1) - When we logout from application, we redirect to logout. However, clicking on login, immediately brings us back into application unless we logout explicitly from fb. It is similar to any other social login, so not a problem (tested SO). But is there a way to logout completely from fb if we logout from application? Pardon my naive-ness, is it a general practice to keep login session unless logged out from the provider explicitly?

Comment: You can try Facebook Javascript SDK, it has 'FB.logout()' function that logs out FB completelly.